# Cannot successfully create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive

Tags: live-usb, system-installation

I am trying to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive.

I tried the Universal USB Installer and UNETbootin to create it but when I booted the 
USB stick,

```
error loading operating system
```

shows up. I tried changing the BIOS to boot from USB by default but always got the same error message.

When I was in the Universal USB Installer it gave me this error message:

> can not open output file autorun.inf

Also an error prompt opens:

```
An error occurred while executing syslinux.
Your usb drive won't be bootable.
```

when it was extracting from 7zip.

The drive is formatted as exFAT. I'm not sure if that is important.

Edit: re-downloading the iso didn't work or formatting the drive.

Edit 2: Since I couldn't format it as normal FAT I formatted it as NTFS and that worked.

Comment: have you tried remaking the live usb?

Comment: Try re-downloading the Ubuntu ISO from the official website http://www.ubuntu.com , the ISO on your computer might be corrupted.

Comment: I too have found this on numerous occasions. Often a reformat of the USB stick to simple FAT and then a redownload of the ISO or just restarting UNetbootin does the trick.

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, you are [encouraged to add your own](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) answer below instead of editing it into the question. This is a Q&A site, so the questions are separate from the answers.

Comment: I second it. As @minerz029 mentioned, it is better to answer your own question and mark it as the answer which will benefit users who're searching for similar issues & also will reduce answering queue.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-formatting the flash drive to Ext2/3/4, and then when you install, have it format to FAT. That has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to format your usb drive and then using unetbootin you can create it bootable.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using lili usb creator and it has never let me down here is a link where you can [download](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) it